How is switching of measurement ranges in instruments, like oscilloscopes, realized nowadays?
I have a more than 20 year old oscilloscope from the German manufacturer Hameg. When I change the voltage range on a channel, I can hear a clicking noise, which I assume is a relay, switching internal circuits to adapt to the new measurement ranges.
How is this realized nowadays? Are relays still in use or do they use integrated switches? (especially in context of „extreme“ measurement ranges, i.e. very high frequencies, ultra-low voltages and currents)

I am afraid this question might be a bit too broad - I believe there is no "one size fits all answer". In the end it probably boils down to a number of things. Anecdotally, I can tell that on my bench I have a top of the line 8ch Lecroy scope, and I do not hear any clicking - but maybe it's just too faint for me to hear :)

If it's 20 year old Hameg, then the "click" is probably just the switch itself.

@JRE, it‘s not the switch itself :-) it’s „something“ inside and it doesn’t click for every change of the switch but only when the range changes by a factor of 10 or so (I will pay closer attention for the switching/clicking points next time)

Small sealed telecom style relays are frequently used. They have many advantages over solid-state switching (low leakage, low 'on' resistance, low capacitance, high voltage capability) and are reasonably inexpensive and small. There are latching types available that draw no power when not switching and therefore have very little thermal EMF.

Many extreme precision designs use both reed relays (some using fancy low thermal EMF types) and telecom relays. Examples of this would be Keysight 6.5 and 8.5 digit multimeters.

Thanks! I somewhat was expecting that mechanical switches might have those advantages w.r.t. resistance, capacity etc.. I assume the reason why I cannot hear any "classic" relay switching sound in modern instruments is that they use those smaller relays, which cannot really be heard.

They make a soft click. Reeds make more of a twang.

Here is a more extreme example of a mechanical 70 GHz switch, with a short GIF of it in operation.

@pipe Excellent. Very elegant. An EE looking at the carcass of a R&S or similarly engineered test instrument is a bit like it must  have been in the 18th/19th century for med students dissecting cadavers. Just the shielding techniques in their FPH spectrum analyzers are worthy of a book.

Can you comment more on thermal EMF? Are you describing the coil heating up and causing a thermal drift? What is this thermal drift -- is it copper resistance, resistor temp-co, peltier/seebeck effect, or some other thermal effect?   It makes sense, but I'm not fully understanding how some small 50mW coil consumption could affect accuracy worse than, for instance, a 20C-30C swing of operating temperatures one would see in a lab.

It's like a tiny offset voltage that appears across the contacts due to dissimilar metals and thermal gradients. The resolution on a meter might be 100nV so a microvolt or two that drifts around as the relay heats (think of time constants in the minutes) is not nice at all. Temperature swings themselves are not necessarily an issue- it's gradients and inadvertent thermocouples.

These telecom relays also tend to have very low wetting voltage/current, which is important for measurement applications. I believe they're also designed for a longer cycle life than most power relays, since their original application requires fairly frequent switching.

Reed Relays are still pretty good - if not the best - signal switches. With an extremely good ratio of Off/On impedance, they are much better than FET switches, as far as I know.
Their drawback is that they cannot switch very fast and they wear out eventually, but this both irrelevant for fixed-range gain switches.

Thanks! I always had this mental image of large oversized relays in mind, maybe because my Hameg sounds like these. Reed relays didn't cross my mind.
